# Best way to add script's working folder to import() path for Python on Windows? 

Tags: python, windows, cross-platform, working-directory

I have a python program which I compile down to a Windows .exe using py2exe.
Using [Inno Setup](http://www.jrsoftware.org/isinfo.php), I create a Windows installer.

The nature of my program is such that it uses plugins which are later imported using the `__import__()` statement. These plugins are located in a 'plugins' folder, which itself is located as a subfolder of where my program's .exe file resides.

Now, to have the program find the plugins, it earlier had the following statement somwhere at the top of my file:

```
sys.path+= ['.']
```

However, this was not working well when the user started the program through Windows' start menu, because apparently the working folder was set to the start menu (instead of where the .exe is located). So `'.'` did not resolve to what I wanted.

I fixed it by changing the statement to the following, so that the `__import__()` statement also looks in the folder where the .exe is located (because `argv[0]` is the full path of the executable):

```
sys.path+= [os.path.dirname(sys.argv[0])]
```

However, I am not sure if I picked the right solution. Especially, because my program is meant to be cross-platform (Windows, OSX, Linux) and the [sys.argv documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/sys.html#sys.argv) says about argv[0] that 'it is operating system dependent whether this is a full pathname or not'.

Should I solve this differently, or is my approach OK?

Answer (score 3):

In my compiled to .exe Qt programms, I'm using code very similar to yours:

```
def executable_path():
    self_file = unicode(sys.argv[0], sys.getfilesystemencoding())
    return os.path.realpath(os.path.dirname(self_file))
```

I'm using unicode because path may contain non ascii symbols.

> sys.argv[0] it is operating system dependent whether this is a full pathname or not

`os.path.realpath` solves that problem.

Answer (score 3):

Why not have a [config](http://docs.python.org/library/configparser.html) file with the path to the plugins dir? This lets the user move it, and you can have one for each os. Stick it with the executable, or maybe a couple well used locations, ~ or /etc on linux, and %homepath% on windows.

Comment: Yes, I am planning something like this as a future feature. But in the meantime I want to have the more basic solution of having a single location (relative to the executable) working correctly. Thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: @Rabarberski If it's a simple solution you want, how about having the plugins live in the same folder as the exe?

Answer (score 1):

I often use this:

```
os.chdir(sys.argv[0].rsplit(os.sep, 1)[0])
```

that makes runtime consistent with development environment, where you run your script from it's directory.

Comment: Makes sense. Why don't you use `os.path.dirname(sys.argv[0])` instead of your `rsplit` approach? The `dirname` approach seems more self-documenting to me, and perhaps catches some special (cross-platform) cases.

Answer (score 0):

Please use `__file__` of the module. You can write like

`sys.path+=os.path.dirname(mymodule.__file__)`

This will add your module's parent directory in sys.path.

Comment: Hmm, I am not convinced because `__file__` returns for my Windows .exe program:  `C:\Program Files (x86)\myprogram\myprogram.exe\core.pyc`. That would require me to strip two levels of the returned path (`core.pyc` and `myprogram.exe`) which might not be the case on OSX, Linux, or even just when running from the terminal.

Comment: Then best solution is config file mention by @SpencerRathbun